Windows snipping tool and WindowsGraphicsCapture generates black rect
In our Windows desktop app, some windows needs to be excluded from capture. Following API is being used to exclude from capture:
SetWindowDisplayAffinity(pShowHideDialog->m_hWnd, WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE);

On first time when window is displayed, capture excludes this window properly. But upon hide/show of window is causing black rect in place of window where affinity was set. Following API is used to show and hide window respectively:
ShowWindow(m_hWnd, SW_HIDE);

ShowWindow(m_hWnd, SW_SHOW);

Below screen shot explains this:

Currently to avoid this problem, instead of using ShowWindow API, moving this window outside of display area and bringing the same window back avoids the problem. But this looks like OS bug on Windows.
OS details:

Operating System: Windows 11 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 22631)
(22621.ni_release.220506-1250)

Behaviour is same with both Windows snipping tool and using WindowsGraphicsCapture
Any idea on how to solve this?

Same situation here. It seems that adding the extended window style WS_EX_LAYERED to the window resolves this (I do not know why).
Source: github.com/electron/....
About layered windows:
Microsoft docs
